# Best labelled dataset for training a binary image classifier

Tags: classification, dataset, labeling

I want to train some binary classifiers in Keras (e.g. to decide if there is person on a picture or if there is a vehicle on it). What is the best dataset to use for this? I mean datasets like [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_datasets_for_machine_learning_research#Object_detection_and_recognition). And are there some pre-trained binary classifiers available online?